# firefox html5 video ended not working

Tags: jquery, html, video

I'm having a little problem with the html5 video tag. Everything works as expectet in chrome and Safari. The video plays and after it finished a function is started. This does not happen in firefox. The video plays just fine, but after it's finished the function is not starting.
Here are the codes:

html:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" autobuffer controls>
            <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

jquery:

```
$('#playedVideo video').bind("ended", function(){
    $("#playedVideo").stop().animate({"bottom":"2000px"},800);
    showBtns();
});
```

and here's the .htaccess:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/mp4 .m4a
AddType audio/wav /wav
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does seem to work, but it doesn't seem to take effect because of the default value of `position` attribute of the element in Firefox.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75zFP/3/) where I've changed the `position` attribute's value of the `<video>` element to `absolute`.

Comment: actually I have a wrapper around the <video> which is positioned:absolute, that's the #playedVideo I'm trying to animate in the code

Comment: How many wrappers do you have around your video tag? Seems like you are using the ID `playVideo` for the bind function but `playedVideo` ID in the next line. Is that a typo or do you have two separate IDs?

Comment: it's a typo, but i have fixed it i my original code, and nothing changes
#playedVideo is the wrapper, and with "#playVideo video" I'm binding the video tag to "ended"

Comment: Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75zFP/4/). It has the same jQuery code that you provided with a wrapper, and it seems to work for me in Firefox. Maybe you have got some of your HTML wrong in your code?

Comment: I have the same code, but even when I place an alert right after the "ended"-event, firefox doesn't react. Your fiddle actually does work for me too in firefox...this is weird

could this be a problem with the .htaccess file, because I had to add one to make the html5 video work in firefox at all?

Comment: The .htaccess configuration would have nothing to do with this since jQuery works completely inside the browser, whereas the .htaccess settings are executed on the server. I could help if you shared your web page or if you could replicate your problem in a jsfiddle.

Comment: same things happening here.
@user2839873 ! did you get the solution?